# I can't get the sql string namely address to appear once my session is set in my html code?

Tags: php, html, sql, session, post

I am trying to get the results from my $address query to show in my html code but it only returns number 0 or if I change it to echo $address and it return Resource id #6. Keep in mind this is my first php attempt so be kind!

```
<?php

include_once'config/connect.php'; //database connection

if($_POST['submit']) {

        $address = mysql_query("SELECT location FROM venue
                             WHERE vid in (select vid from  user_venue where id in (select id from iangadot_user where username='".$_POST['username']."' )) ");


            //redirect to your client page...
             //SET YOUR session


        if(mysql_num_rows($address)) {

    $_SESSION['address'] = $address;
        header("Location: clientpag.php");

    }



         else {
            echo "<script language=javascript>alert('Wrong username or password')</script>";
            //header("Location: ./?errorlogged=err");


        }

}


 ?>
```

I have my html code below:

```
<input class = "field" placeholder= "<?php echo $_SESSION['address'] ?>" type="text" >
```

Comment: Is `session_start();` in all your files? I see no mention of it. If not, include it at the top of all files, which is most likely the problem.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is included.

Comment: Stop using the deprecated mysql_* functions and switch to something like mysqli or PDO. The reason this is not working is because you are storing a resource id... not the actual query results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql_query returns a resource not a string so perhaps you should try

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($address);
$_SESSION['address'] = $row['location'];
```

p.s. Follow the advice of tlenss and switch to [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)